# Spring two different application context - property placeholder collision

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I have been created an SDK using Spring framework that will be used
to integrate with a REST backend, to make use of the dependency injection.

In this SDK, I have `MapPropertySources` to handle `PropertyPlaceHolders`.
Basically I register programmatically some properties there which I want
to be resolved within the SDK with `@Value` annotation.

It works fine within the SDK, but when I build the SDK (using the builder)
inside a `Spring-boot` app, the properties from `MapPropertiesPlaceHolder`
are not resolved any longer.

I have this piece of code from the builder class:

```
    public MyRepository build() {


    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

    StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
    context.setEnvironment(env);


    Map<String, Object> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
    propertiesMap.put("baseUrl", baseUrl);

    MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources = context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources();
    mutablePropertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("customPropertiesMap", propertiesMap));


    if(jerseyClient == null){
        jerseyClient = JerseyClientBuilder.createClient();
    }

    context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("jerseyClient", jerseyClient);

    context.setParent(null);
    context.register(MySdk.class);
    context.refresh();

    MySdk mySdk = new MySSdk(context);

    return mySdk;
}
```

This is the way I instantiate the SDK and I create a new
Spring context inside it.

The problem is that the properties within the `MapPropertySource`
are not resolved when I use the SDK as a maven dependency in another
`spring-boot` application. It might have anything to do with the parent
context? The properties are just not resolved... Where should I investigate?

Long problem short, I have the `@Value('${baseUrl})` being resolved within the SDK's tests, but when I include this SDK in another `spring-boot` application, it will not be resolved anylonger. Why?

Edit:

`MySdk` class looks like this:

```
@ComponentScan
@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DeviceRepository {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    public MySdk(){
    }

    public MySdk(ApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    // other methods that calls beans from context like
    // this.context.getBean(MyBean.class).doSomething()
```

Everything works fine in the tests from within the same SDK. The 
`baseUrl` property is resolved fine, but when I wire this SDK in another
spring application, the properties passed in the builder, they are not
recognised by the `@Value` annotation.

Comment: Haven't loaded properties this way since I typically run with property files or cloud config, but shouldn't you register your instance of MySdk to the context not just the class itself?

Comment: I've edited the post, added also MySdk class. I do feel strange the way that spring handles two ore more contexts, because there is the problem that I have. Probably, the context of my SDK (which is instantiated in another spring context) does some magic inside that `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` which I am not aware of... I was expecting that this context within this SDK to be isolated from others, but it seems that Spring does too much magic behind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in your Spring configuration?  Whenever property resolution fails inside of an `@Value` annotation, this is one of the first things that comes to mind.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Link to Javadoc:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html

Comment: This was right, I was debugging in a wrong direction. I guess that spring boot creates this bean automatically for you, but if you don't use spring boot and only spring framework, you have to create it. Not sure how is exactly the lifecycle of the property sources, but the problem was not because I had 2 spring contexts like I thought initially.

Answer (score 0):

hmm just read something interesting about leveraging the java configuration with property placeholders.  Check out this link #3.  It looks like you have to register another bean.

http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/

Also worth noting there is a whole scope discussion on child vs parent contexts.  I don't believe you can have two contexts without creating this relationship.